# Merge video with Images according to resoulution of natural size

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, avasset

I am trying to merge stickers on a video. It works with the landscape right now and lots of issues with portrait videos.

With the landscape issue is on merge, I am unable to maintain sticker ratio and origin according to the video's natural size. With portrait, it's a total mess. If anyone wants to look out for the code and wants to test it, here is the [GitHub link](https://github.com/BhavinBhadani/VideoImageMerge).

Here are the main 2 methods that matters

1st is to get resolution of video and according to that manage video container size that contains images

```
private func setupVideoPlayer() {
    let currentFrameSize = currentVideoFrameSize()
    
    videoeHeightConstraint.constant = currentFrameSize.height
    videoWidthConstraint.constant = currentFrameSize.width
    
    videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: currentFrameSize.width, height: currentFrameSize.height)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    
    videoContentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    videoContentView.bringSubviewToFront(stickersContentView)
    videoPlayer?.play()
}

private func currentVideoFrameSize() -> CGSize {
    guard let asset = playerItem?.asset as? AVURLAsset, let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return .zero }
    let trackSize      = track.naturalSize
    let videoViewSize  = videoContentView.superview!.bounds.size
    let trackRatio     = trackSize.width / trackSize.height
    let videoViewRatio = videoViewSize.width / videoViewSize.height
    
    var newSize: CGSize
    if videoViewRatio > trackRatio {
        newSize = CGSize(width: trackSize.width * videoViewSize.height / trackSize.height, height: videoViewSize.height)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: videoViewSize.width, height: trackSize.height * videoViewSize.width / trackSize.width)
    }
    
    let assetInfo = VideoManager.shared.orientationFromTransform(transform: track.preferredTransform)
    if assetInfo.isPortrait {
        let tempSize = newSize
        newSize.width = tempSize.height
        newSize.height = tempSize.width
    }
    
    return newSize
}
```

For merge:

```
func makeVideoFrom(video: VideoData, images: [VideoOverlayImage], completion:@escaping Completion) -> Void {
    var outputSize: CGSize = .zero
    var insertTime: CMTime = .zero
    var arrayLayerInstructions: [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction] = []
    var arrayLayerImages: [CALayer] = []
                    
    // Init composition
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    // Get video track
    guard let videoTrack = video.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return }
    
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: videoTrack.preferredTransform)
    
    var videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
    if assetInfo.isPortrait == true {
        videoSize.width = videoTrack.naturalSize.height
        videoSize.height = videoTrack.naturalSize.width
    }

    if videoSize.height > outputSize.height {
        outputSize = videoSize
    }

    if outputSize.width == 0 || outputSize.height == 0 {
        outputSize = defaultSize
    }
    
    // Get audio track
    var audioTrack: AVAssetTrack?
    if video.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).count > 0 {
        audioTrack = video.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first
    }
    
    // Init video & audio composition track
    let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                               preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    
    let audioCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio,
                                                               preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    
    do {
        let startTime = CMTime.zero
        let duration = video.asset.duration
        
        // Add video track to video composition at specific time
        try videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: startTime, duration: duration),
                                                  of: videoTrack,
                                                  at: insertTime)
        
        // Add audio track to audio composition at specific time
        if let audioTrack = audioTrack {
            try audioCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: startTime, duration: duration),
                                                      of: audioTrack,
                                                      at: insertTime)
        }
        
        // Add instruction for video track
        let layerInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: videoCompositionTrack!,
                                                                   asset: video.asset,
                                                                   standardSize: outputSize,
                                                                   atTime: insertTime)
        
        // Hide video track before changing to new track
        let endTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration)
        let timeScale = video.asset.duration.timescale
        let durationAnimation = CMTime.init(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: timeScale)
        
        layerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 1.0, toEndOpacity: 0.0, timeRange: CMTimeRange.init(start: endTime, duration: durationAnimation))
        
        arrayLayerInstructions.append(layerInstruction)
        
        // Increase the insert time
        insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration)
    } catch {
        print("Load track error")
    }
    
    // Merge
    for image in images {
        let animatedImageLayer = CALayer()
                    
        let aspectWidth  = assetInfo.isPortrait ? outputSize.width/video.frame.height : outputSize.width/video.frame.width
        let aspectHeight = assetInfo.isPortrait ? outputSize.height/video.frame.width : outputSize.height/video.frame.height
        let aspectRatio = min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)

        let scaledWidth  = image.frame.width * aspectRatio
        let scaledHeight = image.frame.height * aspectRatio
        
        let cx = (image.frame.minX * aspectRatio) + (scaledWidth / 2)
        let cy = (image.frame.minY * aspectRatio) + (scaledHeight / 2)

        var iFrame = image.frame
        iFrame.size.width = scaledWidth
        iFrame.size.height = scaledWidth
        animatedImageLayer.frame = iFrame
        animatedImageLayer.position = CGPoint(x: assetInfo.isPortrait ? cy : cx, y: assetInfo.isPortrait ? cx : cy)
        
        if let animatedURL = URL(string: image.url), let animation = animatedImage(with: animatedURL) {
            animatedImageLayer.add(animation, forKey: "contents")
        }
        
        arrayLayerImages.append(animatedImageLayer)
    }
    
    // Init Video layer
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: outputSize.width, height: outputSize.height)
    
    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: outputSize.width, height: outputSize.height)
    
    parentlayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    
    // Add Image layers
    arrayLayerImages.forEach { parentlayer.addSublayer($0) }
    
    // Main video composition instruction
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: insertTime)
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = arrayLayerInstructions
            
    // Main video composition
    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainComposition.renderSize = outputSize
    mainComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentlayer)
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    
    // Export to file
    let path = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("stickers_video_merge.mov")
    let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    
    // Remove file if existed
    FileManager.default.removeItemIfExisted(exportURL)
    
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter?.outputURL = exportURL
    exporter?.outputFileType = .mov
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter?.videoComposition = mainComposition
    
    // Do export
    exporter?.exportAsynchronously() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.exportDidFinish(exporter: exporter, videoURL: exportURL, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

Major issues:

1. In landscape videos, image origin not maintained also it's size according to natural size looks bigger than expected
2. In portrait videos, I am unable to get the video layer in the background although it's there and playing. it displayed a black view in the end result. Also, image origin and size not maintained according to the original video size.

> You can also check the [dev](https://github.com/BhavinBhadani/VideoImageMerge/tree/dev) branch where you don't need to maintain any ratio but there is an issue with the image frame and portrait video. Anyone can run it on your device and understand the actual problem.

Comment: Can you share any reference video of what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Nikunj I just want to maintain the image layer frame according to video size. I don't have a reference video. I just want to achieve what we are adding on top of video like image on top of it and its position relative to its size